# Adding Stop Loss by TRADE_ACTION_DEAL or TRADE_ACTION_SLTP?

Tags: mql5

According to *Expert Advisor Programming for MetaTrader 5* ...

```
request.action = TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;

[...]

request.sl = 0;

request.tp = 0;

request.deviation = 50;

OrderSend(request,result);
```

...will not work if my broker uses the *market* or *exchange execution* types. I would have to add stop loss and take profit by modifying the order via `request.action = TRADE_ACTION_SLTP;` in hindsight instead, a hack which I would like to do without if possible. But how can I find out which execution type my broker (it's ActiveTrades) uses if not by trial and error (or loss, that is)?

PS: execution types are *Instant*, *Request*, *Market* or *Exchange* execution.

Answer (score 1):

`CTrade.OrderModify()` is for modification. send a plain market order then, after success, modify it, for both ecn and non-ecn brokers